# Calcular Média por períodos SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite, 2 dias de luta consegui chegar nesse resultado, porém, não estou conseguindo tirar a média diária por mÊs e média semanal por ano.

1 Query

```
SELECT a.Ano, a.Mês, a.Reviews
FROM (
    SELECT
        YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
        MONTH(r.DataInclusao) AS Mês,
        COUNT(r.DataInclusao) AS Reviews
    FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
    GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao)
) a
ORDER BY a.Ano, a.Mês
```

Resultado:
[image: resultado]
QUERY 2

```
SELECT a.Dia, a.Mês, a.Ano, a.Reviews
FROM (
    SELECT
        DAY(r.DataInclusao) AS Dia,
        MONTH(r.DataInclusao) AS Mês,
        YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
        COUNT(r.DataInclusao) AS Reviews
    FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
    GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao), DAY(r.DataInclusao)
) a
ORDER BY a.Ano, a.Mês, a.Dia
```

RESULTADO:
[image: resultado]

Comment: já tentou colocar o group by na 1a query, e não apenas na subquery?  na QUERY1, algo assim: `SELECT a.Ano, a.Mês, AVG(a.Reviews) .... GROuPY BY a.Ano, a.Mês ORDER BY a.Ano, a.Mês, a.Dia`

Comment: Assim ele anula a Coluna que ficava o total.
https://prnt.sc/135c1jy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Utilize a Cláusula **`OVER()`**:

A Cláusula `OVER()` utilizada em conjunto com o `PARTITION BY` divide o resultado do *Select* em partições permitindo que você utilize funções que, sem esse artifício, exigia o uso de outras soluções como subconsultas, por exemplo.
Busquei adaptar a cláusula ao código já fornecido na sua pergunta para facilitar o  seu entendimento.

Veja exemplos de uso da cláusula *over* aplicados às suas necessidades:

### Média Diária:

```
SELECT a.Dia, a.Mes, a.Ano, a.Reviews, AVG(Reviews) OVER(PARTITION BY Ano, Mes) AS Media
FROM (
    SELECT
        DAY(r.DataInclusao) AS Dia,
        MONTH(r.DataInclusao) AS Mes,
        YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
        COUNT(r.DataInclusao) AS Reviews
    FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
    GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao), DAY(r.DataInclusao)
) a
ORDER BY a.Ano, a.Mes, a.Dia
```

### Média Mensal:

```
SELECT a.Ano, a.Mes, a.Reviews, AVG(Reviews) OVER(PARTITION BY Ano) AS Media
    FROM (
        SELECT
            YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
            MONTH(r.DataInclusao) AS Mes,
            COUNT(r.DataInclusao) AS Reviews            
        FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
        GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao)
    ) a
ORDER BY a.Ano, a.Mes
```

> **SELECT – Cláusula OVER (Transact-SQL)**:  Determina o particionamento e a ordenação de um conjunto de linhas antes da
> aplicação da função de janela associada. Isto é, a cláusula OVER
> defines uma janela ou conjunto de linhas especificado pelo usuário em
> um conjunto de resultados de consulta. Uma função de janela computa um
> valor para cada linha na janela. Você pode usar a cláusula OVER com
> funções para computar valores agregados como médias móveis, agregações
> cumulativas, somas acumuladas ou os primeiros N resultados por grupo.

Leia mais sobre a cláusula *OVER* em [SELECT – Cláusula OVER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

*Editado*

### Resultado Mês, Ano, Reviews_no_mes, Media_Diaria_no_Mes:

Considerando que o resultado esperado é:
Mês, Ano, Reviews_no_mes, Media_Diaria_no_Mes, uma solução válida é a seguinte:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(r.DataInclusao) AS Mes,
    YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
    SUM(COUNT(r.DataInclusao)) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao)) Reviews_no_mes,
    AVG(COUNT(r.DataInclusao)) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao)) Media_Diaria_no_mes
FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao), DAY(r.DataInclusao)
order by YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao)
```

**Sobre a consulta**
`COUNT(r.DataInclusao)` conta as reviews agrupadas por dia devido o `GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao), DAY(r.DataInclusao)`. Então com base nesse resultado, particionamos para fazer cálculos por ano e mês, somando as contagens diárias por meio do `SUM(COUNT(r.DataInclusao))` da partição, obteremos o total da contagem do mês ao qual chamei de *Reviews_no_mes*. Para obter a média mensal, usamos o comando `AVG(COUNT(r.DataInclusao))` que considerará a média das contagens dos dia do resultado particionado pelo ano mês.

**Outra forma de obter o mesmo resultado esperado:**
Adaptando sua `1 Query`, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT a.Ano, a.Mês, sum(a.Reviews) as total_mes, AVG(a.Reviews) as media_no_mes 
FROM (
    SELECT
        YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
        MONTH(r.DataInclusao) AS Mês,
        COUNT(r.DataInclusao) AS Reviews
    FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
    GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), MONTH(r.DataInclusao), DAY(r.DataInclusao) 
) a
GROUP by Ano, Mês
ORDER BY a.Ano, a.Mês
```

Comment: Opa Clarck, obrigado pela aula, ficou do jeito que eu queria, porém o resultado na média não bate, veja um exemplo nessa imagem.

https://prnt.sc/1361rqh

Comment: Olá @grauzera, você se refere a exatidão decimal da média? Observe essa imagem: http://prntscr.com/136bhpg. Não entendi o trecho *o resultado na média não bate*.  Caso se refira a exatidão do decimal, pode fazer `AVG(Reviews+0.0)` ou fazer um `cast` explícito pra decimal.

Comment: ah, não seria a média total de tudo e sim de cada linha.
eu consegui fazer algo similar, porem não consigo exibir a coluna reviews e sim só a média.
acho que assim fica mais detalhado. -> https://prnt.sc/1370hu2

Comment: @grauzera, resposta foi editada. Incluí o *select* utilizando `over()` e adaptei sua consulta inicial para obter o resultado esperado. Acredito que seja isso que você precisava como resultado.

Comment: Clarck, mais perfeito impossível, muito obrigado pela ajuda.
Consegue me dar uma luz como eu consigo fazer a média semanal nesse mesmo modelo, tentei de algumas formas mas não tive resultado.
teria que ser - media semanal por ano

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ter te ajudado, @grauzera. Veja se o resultado esperado para média semanal é obtido com o SQL seguinte: `SELECT DISTINCT 
    YEAR(r.DataInclusao) AS Ano,
    SUM(COUNT(r.DataInclusao)) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao)) Reviews_no_Ano,
    AVG(COUNT(r.DataInclusao)) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao)) Media_Semanal
FROM ProdutoSkuReview r
GROUP BY YEAR(r.DataInclusao), DATEPART(WEEK,r.DataInclusao)
order by YEAR(r.DataInclusao)`